# SQL get column name,row number of a unique value

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I have got some SQL tables, and the structure of them can change. But there is always one unique value somewhere in a table (value's name is "Channel") and I always need to get the column name and the row number of this value in a current table ( to further get all values in this column with a row number greater as of "Channel") . How could the code for that look like?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: mysql tables are not the same as excel sheets, it is possible to solve your problem, but I cannot imagine why do you need this, any kind of master-slave synchronization?

Comment: Ok, a guy for whom I do this, wants to have the functionality: he can upload some Excelsheet with TV-reports, I have to store this sheet in a new created sql-table.In each Sheet he has a column with Channel-list, but the column is not always named,so mostly the value "Channel" is in row Number 4-10. Above it is some text, that has no meaning. And he does not wnat to ahve a fixed structure,so that this column can change its number and name. But under this value "Channels" is the list of channels. Finally I have to get this list of channels and check if they are in another table.

Comment: I know it sounds a little crazy, but it is the wish of the customer :-)

Comment: So, you do not need to find value in arbitrary column/row/table of your mysql database. You need to open uploaded excel sheet, find proper values/rows and then insert them into mysql table with fixed format

Comment: The thing is, the user can edit the sheet online without generating new Files. The cahnged data is simply updated in SQL,and for the view I simply load the content of updated SQL table.So it could even happen, that he uplaods an empty sheet and than fills it the way he wishes.On buttonclick he checks if all values are proper. So I could get the realtime values only from SQL or with JS if I search for an element with a value "Channels" on the actual screen and after that for all values under it. I hoped that SQL way would be easier

Comment: Nope, sql will not help you here, actually you need to re-think whole logic of your application, when user upload arbitrary data - you need to convert them somehow into fixed workable for you format, or anything else - but DO NOT SUPPOSE columns/rows in mysql table the same way as excel does, they are totally different structure